# Trapping region for $\ddot x + (x^2-2) \dot x + x + \sin(x) =0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I need to show that the system

$$\ddot x + (x^2-2) \dot x + x + \sin(x) =0 $$

Have a periodic orbit. I always use polar coordinates to find a trapping regio, but with the sine term, I am kinda lost. If someone could help me to find something or give me a hint, I would be glad.

Thanks!

Comment: Sure about the text of the homework? Every orbit except the fixed point $x=\dot x=0$ seems to wander to infinity.

Comment: Yes. At least, wolfram shows one. It is a lienard equation, maybe one theorem hold this.

Comment: Right, the orbit is slightly farther from the origin than the region I looked at. Then *apply Liénard's theorem*.

Comment: yes, I did it. Thanks.

Comment: Show what you did by posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Waiting for a soon-to-come solution by the OP, here is a phase diagram (made using free online tools) which shows the cycle enclosing the origin:

[image]

Comment: (-) This does not show your work. And this is easily a comment with a link than an answer.

Comment: @NonStandard No work to show since this is a WA diagram, as mentioned at the beginning of the post. Also mentioned is that this was posted waiting for a full answer by the OP.